# tab indexing in datagrid column in flex

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid, tabindex

I want to know if tab index is possible for data grid column? I have a data grid where I need a functionality to go through columns by pressing tab button of keyboard. I know this thing can be done using item Editor. But I do not want item Editor, what I want, through item renderer. Please let me know if any tutorial or suggestion is there.